# How to Modify a iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Top left position in VB?

Tags: vb.net, itext, drawrectangle

I am Using itextsharp dll in VB to generate a PDF. In the PDF, need to increase space between rectangle and text. I tried to setmargin and changed the rectangle coordinates, but the space between top rectangle and text is not creating. Please see the attachment.
Below is the code i am using to generate PDF

```
                Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(tempFile)
                Dim size As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSize(1)
                Dim AcroAVDoc As Document = New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate())
                AcroAVDoc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                Dim FS As FileStream = New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(AcroAVDoc, FS)
                AcroAVDoc.Open()
                If (SaveDoc) Then
                   
                    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

                    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK)
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)

                    cb.BeginText()
                    Dim text As String = "HeaderText  " + TableData(HeaderText)
                    ''put the alignment And coordinates here
                    cb.SetTextMatrix(240, 583)
                    cb.ShowText(text)
                    cb.EndText()

                    ''create the New page And add it to the pdf
                    Dim Page As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1)
                    Dim psize As Rectangle = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)

                    cb.AddTemplate(Page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, psize.Height)

                    'AcroAVDoc.Save(1, newFile)
                End If
                AcroAVDoc.Close()
                FS.Close()
                writer.Close()
                reader.Close()
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Need to decrease Right space]

Comment: Your code only draws the header text. I don't find that in your image. Your code does not draw a rectangle. So how do your question text, code, and image relate?

Comment: Hi mkl, please see the updated image, the text appears on top, i want to bring the rectangle down

Comment: Try changing the last two parameters of your `cb.AddTemplate` call a bit (e.g. plus or minus 10) and see if the result is towards what you need.

Comment: Great! Do you want to make that an actual answer (in contrast to the mere comments we used)? are shall I do so?

Comment: Hi mkl, yes, you can do so. Also could you please explain the parameters in cb.AddTemplate....Now, i get a space from top. Also, wanted to reduce the space in right side of the rectangle

Comment: I just posted an answer focusing on your original problem. Concerning *"wanted to reduce the space in right side of the rectangle"* - how do you want to reduce it? by moving the rectangle right to get an equal amount to the left and the right? By stretching the rectangle? By making the paper format narrower?

Comment: Hi Mkl, i need to move the rectangle right to get an equal amount to the left and the right

Comment: In that case adapt the two last parameters of `cb.AddTemplate` again - one of them moves the rectangle up and down, the other one left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does (if `SaveDoc` is `true`) is

- creating a new PDF file in `newFile` with landscape A4 page size,
- drawing the string `text` on its first page, and
- drawing the rotated static contents of the first page of the PDF in `tempFile` on the same first page.

Thus, to modify the position of the text relative to content copied from the other file, you have to adjust the position where you draw the text and/or the position where you draw the imported content.

You set the position of the text you draw by setting the text matrix (translation coordinates only):

```vb
cb.SetTextMatrix(240, 583)
```

You set the position of the imported page content you draw by setting the transformation matrix (full matrix):

```vb
cb.AddTemplate(Page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, psize.Height)
```

The second through fifth parameter (`0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0`) define a clockwise rotation by 90° around the bottom left corner and the sixth and seventh parameter (`0, psize.Height`) define an upwards translation. As the rotation around the bottom left corner rotates the content out of the visible page area, that upwards translation is needed to move it back into view.

To tweak the position of the text in relation to the imported page, simply experiment with changing the `240, 583` for the text and/or the `0, psize.Height` for the imported page a bit (e.g. plus or minus 10) until it matches your expectation.